# clearInterval if (condition)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would that if (NArray === 2) {clearInterval()} but i don't know how to do it because if i put it inside the setInterval it obviousy doesn't work and is the same if i put it outside. Thanks to everyone

```
$(function Intervallo(){
    var NArray = -1;
    var ringraziamenti = [
        "",
        "Thanks",
        "You saved my Website",
        "Now you can use it, and try to find all the hidden tresure that there are",
        "Good Luck",
    ];
    $("#Save").click(function() {
        if (NArray === -1) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("head").append('<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Italianno" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><style>body {font-family:"Italianno", cursive; font-weight:800; font-size:36px;}</style>');
        }, 3000);
        setInterval(function () {
            NArray = NArray + 1;
            $("#magia").remove();
            $("#BGimage").css("background-image", "url(../../Desktop/Senza%20titolo-1.png)");
            $("#ringraziamenti").html(ringraziamenti[NArray]);
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: You haven't stored the [intervalD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).  Also, when called properly, `clearInterval` will work inside the timed function too.

Comment: where do you call `setInterval`?

Comment: could you try to help me @Teemu?

Comment: Declare an intervalID at the beginning of the IIFE, then just set `intervalID = setInterval(...);`, and when clearing, pass the id to the function: `clearInterval(intervalID);`.

Comment: The DOC explains how to use `clearInterval()`

Comment: *"if i put it inside the setInterval it obviousy doesn't work"* - Putting clearInterval() inside the timed function is quite a common practice and works perfectly well. Assuming you actually use the interval id previously returned by setInterval().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is:

```js
$(function Intervallo() {
  // declare variable to save the return value of setInterval
  var interval = null;
  var NArray = -1;
  var ringraziamenti = [
    "",
    "Thanks",
    "You saved my Website",
    "Now you can use it, and try to find all the hidden tresure that there are",
    "Good Luck",
  ];
    $("#Save").click(function () {
    if (NArray === -1) {
    if (interval != null) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
    }
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
    $("head").append('<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Italianno" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><style>body {font-family:"Italianno", cursive; font-weight:800; font-size:36px;}</style>');
    }, 3000);
    // save the return value of setInterval
    interval = setInterval(function () {
    NArray = NArray + 1;
    if (NArray == 2) { // when NArray is 2 stop setInterval
       NArray = -1;
       clearInterval(interval);
       interval = null;
    }
    $("#magia").remove();
    $("#BGimage").css("background-image", "url(../../Desktop/Senza%20titolo-1.png)");
    $("#ringraziamenti").html(ringraziamenti[NArray]);
}, 3000);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="Save">Save</button>
```

Comment: @PeppedocBrown you can remove the button. It is only a example. If you forget the button you need to pay attention to the content inside the function: interval varaible and how it's used to clear setTimer.